# VS2010 ASP.NET Split View Designer Real Time Update

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

When I type in the source side of (for example) default.aspx, I do not see my changes immediately in the Designer side. Instead, I see a message that tells me that "Design view is out of sync with Source view. Click here to synchronize views."

To me, the lack of real time updates completely defeats the purpose of split view. Is there a way to make Design view auto-sync, and stay updated in real time?

Comment: May this help you .[THE DESIGN VIEW IS OUT OF SYNC WITH SOURCE VIEW IN VISUAL STUDIO.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2013/06/20/web-user-control-design-view-doesnt-render-in-designer-once-any-source-editing-is-done/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below URL, see if it helps you.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/30/enabling-vertical-split-view-in-vs-2008.aspx

Comment: Thanks. The comments of this article indicated that this was an intentional design decision. I've included the relevant post for other who may be interested:

"In are origional design we had live updates as you typed, but we found that performance wise it didn't make sense to-do the sync on every keystroke.  Note that you don't have to switch the views to-do the sync, you can either save the file and it will do an automatic sync, or press the Ctrl-Shift-Y key in order to-do a sync without saving."